# StopIteration error/ exception/ bug while using multiple if condition and next()

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, iterator, stopiteration

I used jupyter notebook here.

This code is from a youtube video. It was working in the youtuber's computer but mine raise a Stopiteration error

Here I am trying to get all the titles(questions from the csv) that are questions related to 'Go' language

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("Questions.csv", encoding = "ISO-8859-1", usecols = ["Title", "Id"])

titles = [_ for _ in df.loc[lambda d: d['Title'].str.lower().str.contains(" go "," golang ")]['Title']]
```

**#new cell**

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_sm" , disable= ["ner"])
```

**#new cell**

```
def has_golang(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for t in doc:    
        if t.lower_ in [' go ', 'golang']:
            if t.pos_ != 'VERB':
                if t.dep_ == 'pobj':
                    return True
    return False

g = (title for title in titles if has_golang(title))
[next(g) for i in range(10)]
```

**#This is the error**

```
StopIteration                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-56-862339d10dde> in <module>
      9 
     10 g = (title for title in titles if has_golang(title))
---> 11 [next(g) for i in range(10)]

<ipython-input-56-862339d10dde> in <listcomp>(.0)
      9 
     10 g = (title for title in titles if has_golang(title))
---> 11 [next(g) for i in range(10)]

StopIteration:
```

As far as I have done the research I think it might be a bug

All I want to do is get those titles that satisfy the 3 'if' conditions

[link to the youtube video](https://youtu.be/WnGPv6HnBok)

Comment: If you're trying to get the elements of g from its generator just use `elements = list(g)`.  Using `[next(g) for i in range(10)]` will have a stopiteration error unless there are 10 or more items in the generator.

Comment: it is returning empty square bracket  ' [ ] '

Comment: can you be more specific where should I exactly put that piece of code. I replaced the [next(g) for i in range(10)] with your suggestion

Comment: @vedant--checking the video you changed the expression for titles.  The video has `titles = [_ for _ in df.loc[lambda d: d['Title'].str.lower().str.contains("go")]['Title']]`

Comment: yep it worked. thank you. I thought tweaking in that part of line would make it faster

Comment: @vedant--issue is signature of function contains is [str.contains(pat, case=True, flags=0, na=None, regex=True)](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html).  You're passing two arguments i.e. `" go "," golang "`.  The first will correspond to pat and the second to case (i.e. will not be used for golang, so this has no effect).  As mentioned in the video placing spaces around the word causes problems since you won't recognize if the word appears at the beginning or end of a sentence.  You could try pat = r"\bgo|golang\b" as a regex.

Answer (score 2):

The `StopIteration` is the result of calling `next()` on an exhausted iterator, i.e. `g` produces less than 10 results. You can get this information from the `help()` function.

```py
help(next)
Help on built-in function next in module builtins:
next(...)
    next(iterator[, default])
    
    Return the next item from the iterator. If default is given and the iterator
    is exhausted, it is returned instead of raising StopIteration.
```

#### Edit

Your `has_golang` is incorrect. The first test is always `False` because `nlp` tokenizes words, i.e. trims the leading and trailing spaces. Try this:

```py
def has_golang(text):
    doc = nlp(text)
    for t in doc:    
        if t.lower_ in ['go', 'golang']:
            if t.pos_ != 'VERB':
                if t.dep_ == 'pobj':
                    return True
    return False
```

I figured this out by finding a title which should result in `True` from `has_golang`. I then ran the following code:

```py
doc = nlp("Making a Simple FileServer with Go and Localhost Refused to Connect")
print("\n".join(str((t.lower_, t.pos_, t.dep_)) for t in doc))
```

```
('making', 'VERB', 'csubj')
('a', 'DET', 'det')
('simple', 'PROPN', 'compound')
('fileserver', 'PROPN', 'dobj')
('with', 'ADP', 'prep')
('go', 'PROPN', 'pobj')
('and', 'CCONJ', 'cc')
('localhost', 'PROPN', 'conj')
('refused', 'VERB', 'ROOT')
('to', 'PART', 'aux')
('connect', 'VERB', 'xcomp')
```

Then looking at `('go', 'PROPN', 'pobj')`, it's obvious that PROPN is not VERB, and pobj is pobj, so the issue has to be with the token: go, specifically `"go"` not `" go "`.

---

#### Original Response

If you just want the titles that satisfy the 3 `if` conditions, skip the generator:

```py
g = list(filter(has_golang, titles))
```

If you need the generator but also want a list:

```py
g = (title for title in titles if has_golang(title))
list(g)
```

Comment: I tried list(g) but it gave me ' [ ] ' an empty bracket

Comment: I need it to show all the titles satisfying those if conditions

Comment: That's because nothing in titles satisfies the `if` conditions. Please provide `Questions.csv`. It is difficult to diagnose why `g` is empty without the source data.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/stackoverflow/stacksample?select=Questions.csv

Comment: you might understand the problem better with the video https://youtu.be/WnGPv6HnBok look from 18:02 in the video

Comment: OK, so something is wrong with `has_golang()`. What have you tried in order to see what's going on in `has_golang()`?

Comment: As I commented above, the OP expression for titles is incorrect (i.e. doesn't follow the video).  Should be: `titles = [_ for _ in df.loc[lambda d: d['Title'].str.lower().str.contains("go")]['Title']]`.

Comment: @DarrylG, yup, and by padding the `str.contains` arguments with spaces the OP excludes titles which end with `go` or `golang`.

Comment: @MichaelRuth--another issue is to match multiple keywords OP needed `‘|’.join(include Keywords)`.  Having `...str.contains(" go "," golang ")` only picks up the first keyword i.e. " go " (i.e. " golang " ignored).

Comment: Yeah, I guess I don't understand what the OP wants. If the OP wants the same result as in the video then just copy the code from the video, it's pretty simple.

Comment: yep it worked. thank you. I thought tweaking in that part of line would make it faster but that messed it up. And thanks for telling me about the str.contains() part, I will remember that

Comment: @vedant, channel Dr. Knuth: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize